# Slick slider remove last slide if winWidth < 500

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Using [slick slide](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), I'm trying to remove the last slide (slide 6) if the window width is less than 500.

I have set up slick slider here -  [JS Fiddle Slick Slider](https://jsfiddle.net/e14qpbqb/1/)

According to the documentation, the slideRemove function is the following Javascript

```
$('.add-remove').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});
$('.js-add-slide').on('click', function() {
  slideIndex++;
$('.add-remove').slick('slickAdd','<div><h3>' + slideIndex + '</h3></div>');
});

$('.js-remove-slide').on('click', function() {
$('.add-remove').slick('slickRemove',slideIndex - 1);
 if (slideIndex !== 0){
 slideIndex--;
}
});
```

I need help with changing the `.on('click')` function from the docs to change at 500 winWidth.

Comment: Do you have remove button to remove slide or you want your code to remove slide on page load/resize?

Comment: @pratikwebdev  remove slide on page load/resize . Slide (6) , Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need 2 events one on window resize and one on load. Also define a variable to store number of slides.

```
$(window).resize(function(evt){

    if($(document).width()<500 && noOfSlides > 5)
    {
      alert($( document ).width());
      $('.slider').slick('slickRemove',5);
   }
});
```

Here I have hardcoded slide 6 to be removed with a check of noOfslides greater than 5.

you could see it working here. https://jsfiddle.net/g7z93ur6/

Comment: how would you do this if the number of slides is always different?

Answer (score 0):

Another idea:
If screen size is changed again to bigger size, the slide 6 is still not there (because it was removed before).
You can use slick filters (for example ":even" or ":last-of-element"):

```
function checkSizeAndFilterSlickDivs(elementId){
            if($(document).width()<500)
            {
                $(elementId).slick('slickFilter',':even');
            }
            else {
                $(elementId).slick('slickUnfilter');
            }
        }
checkSizeAndFilterSlickDivs('.add-remove');
                        $(window).resize(function(){
                            checkSizeAndFilterSlickDivs('#offer-' + idOfElement + '-div');
});
```

This helped me changing from small/medium screen sizes to big size and still having all slick divs available.